# Returning objects from mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following code in my User.js class:

```
exports.findUser = function(nameIn){
  User.find({
    name: nameIn
  });
)};
```

How can I make it 'return' the users it found? Something is telling me that using "return" is not best practice on Node? I think I need to use callbacks but, how?

this is the code I am using to call the function:

```
var User = require("../models/user.js");

User.findUser(req.params.name, function(users) {
  console.log(users);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In findUser you don't seem to be providing a place for that callback to go. The mongoose query itself also returns the document(s or error) to a callback to be handled.

If you wanted to modify your `findUser` to fit with how you seem to be using it:

```
exports.findUser = function(nameIn,callback){
  User.find({name: nameIn}, function(err,user) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    callback(user)
  });
)};
```

The results of mongoose's query (successful or not) are handed to the function in the arguments of the query (as a callback), which is in line with the asynchronous nature of Node. The other generally accepted methods of handling Node's non-blocking I/O are [events](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) and [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), with methods like [promises](https://npmjs.org/package/q) being viable if somewhat controversial.

Mongoose itself uses [callbacks in its guides](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html), but also has [promises available](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise).

Looking at your function now, you're handing it the name to query, and what you'd like to do with the returned documents as a callback. The mongoose function itself already has the capability of doing everything:

```
User.find({name: req.params.name}, function(err,user) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  console.log(user);
});
```

Defining `findUser` may only be worthwhile if you have a lot of things to play with in that document that `findUser` will keep DRY.

Comment: Yes. The key point is that mongoose queries are not synchronous, so you'll need to provide a callback function to handle the results/error later.

Comment: thank you. so the way you are suggesting is the best practice?

Comment: also yes, I know it might be kind of an overkill to have a function that calls another similar one, but I might have to do more work inside the model before returning it to the controller.